# "Four times greater chance" vs. "four times greater of a chance"

Tags: grammaticality, prepositions, indefinite-articles

> Researchers from Finland's National Research and Development Center for Welfare and Health discovered that **women who participate in an abortion have four times greater chance of dying** in the following year than women who chose to give birth to their child.

Is the bolded part grammatical? Or should it be changed to read "… have four times greater *of a* chance of dying"?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's OK as it stands, though it should really be *... have **a** four times greater chance of dying*.

I would go so far as to say it should **absolutely not** be changed as proposed.

However... we live in transitionary times. I see that "of a" construction creeping in all over the place. To older UK ears, it sounds like an Americanism, which probably means it will become the norm eventually.